# How does electromagnetic news travells?

Tags: electromagnetism

A charge particle is moving at constant velocity and an another charge particle is placed at some distance.we know that the charge particle will experince force due to some earlier position of charge particle because electromagnetic news travels at a finite velocity which is speed of light but how does this electromagnetic news travels as the charge particle is moving with constant velocity there will be no electromagnetic wave??

Answer (score 0):

The electromagnetic *field* travels out with the speed of light. The electromagnetic "wave", or "radiation", is only the part of the electromagnetic field that attenuates its amplitude according to the *1/r* rule. Besides this part, the other part, which attenuates its amplitude according to the *1/r^2* rule, also travels out with the speed of light.